# How do I get Arduino to communicate with Processing?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, processing

I wanted to make my Arduino communicate with Processing.

On Arduino, I use the code taken from the [Processing](https://processing.org/tutorials/electronics/) site (Example 1A):

```cpp
int switchPin = 4;                      // Switch connected to pin 4

void setup()
{
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);            // Set pin 0 as an input
  Serial.begin(9600);                   // Initialize serial communications at a 9600 baud rate
}

void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(switchPin) == HIGH)   // If switch is ON,
                                        // send 1 to Processing
  {
    Serial.write(1);
  }
  else
  {                                // If the switch is not ON,
    Serial.write(0);               // send 0 to Processing
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

While in Processing I use this code:

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;    // Create object from Serial class
String val = "0"; // Data received from the serial port

void setup()
{
  size(200, 200);
  frameRate(10);
  String portName = Serial.list()[0]; // Change the 0 to a 1, 2,
                                      // etc. to match your port.
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw()
{
  if (myPort.available() > 0)
  {
    // If data is available,
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n'); // Read it and store it in val
  }
  background(255);
  if(val.equals("0"))
  {
    fill(0);
  }
  else
  {
    fill(204);
  }
  rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
```

The program gives me the error *NullPointerException* on line 22 in the Processing program.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hi, Marco! Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you edit your question and add the exact error you're getting? Maybe the error is happening because you're accessing `val` outside the if, so on the first loop it might still be null. Maybe try initializing it with a "0" to see what happens. Let me know if it works so I can post a propper answer :)

Comment: Hi @George! The error I was getting was "NullPointerException" in line 22, sorry but I forgot to mention it. Now I made the changes you suggested to me by putting String val = "0"; but nothing has changed. He keeps giving me the error on line 22.

Answer (score 0):

There is a delay in the communication and it is possible that the first time when the *draw* function is called, the serial port doesn't send any data, and the value received is null. That might be the reason you get the NullPointerException.

Try this:

```java
void draw()
{
  while (myPort.available() > 0)
  {
    // If data is available,
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');   // Read it and store it in val
  }

  background(255);

  if(val != null)
  {
    if(val.equals("0"))
    {
      fill(0);
    }
    else
    {
     fill(204);
    }
  }
  rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
```